Python tkinter code refuses to run with vscode
I am brushing up on my python and as a a part of that I wanted to relearn tkinter. I am running into an issue where whenever I try to run the code through vscode it wont let me and it gives me a module not found error. I know that it is not an issue with my code since when I use a separate terminal it runs fine. I would deal with this but my terminal is constantly closing with no apparent reason. If I try to install tkinter on vscodes terminal it says that the module doesn't exist
To install it I ran: pip install python3-tkinter
I got the errors: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-tkinter
I am running fedora 40 and I am using the interpreter that vscode says is recommended which is python 3.11.9 64-bit in /bin/python3

Please consider including the actual commands you're using to install tkinter and include the traceback errors that you're using.  As posted, it's difficult to know what the issue is.

What module?  Remember that, depending on which extension you use, VSCode installs its own installation of Python, separate from the one you run at a terminal.  You can override that in your VSCode config.

Ensure that VSCode is utilizing the correct Python interpreter, reinstall the Python extension, and check the VSCode settings. It is difficult to provide assistance without more information about the issues or system configuration. Can you supply this information?

@CpGowtham I just updated it with that info

tkinter module cannot be installed using pip.

In the python installation screen, you can select tcl/tk in the optional features, which will install the corresponding version of tkinter for you.

tkinter cannot be installed by pip. You could use command sudo dnf install python3-tkinter in Fedora.

To fix Tkinter issues on Fedora, use sudo dnf install python3-tkinter instead of pip. Also, in VSCode, select the correct Python interpreter via the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and Python: Select Interpreter.

I tried every option that appears for Python interpreters in vscode and none work. I ran that command and it said it was already installed

Note that python3-tkinter is for Python 3.12.  Install python3.11-tkinter for Python 3.11.
